# Properties of Markov Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm interested in a physical problem that I have been modelling with a Markov process. $\psi(z)$ is randomly varying and can be modelled by a stationary and ergodic process whose stationary distribution is uniform over $[0,2\pi].$ One can then assume that $\psi(z)$ is a Markov process on the torus with generator satisfying the Fredholm alternative.

I have an integral of the form

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[\sin 2 \psi(0) \sin 2 \psi(z)]  d z.$$

Is the quantity $\psi(z=0)$ random?